# Excel function goal seek

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, goalseek

I have 2 questions about the Goal Seek function:

1. Can I set the "To value:" to equal the value of a specific cell such as `U3`?
2. How can I do this function for 5 cells at the same time?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To answer your first question: Use a helper cell with the formula `=AC21-U3`. Choose that cell as the "Set cell" range and use zero for the "To value".

Comment: As for the second part, perhaps copy the whole sheet, then only change U5 for each copy. Redo goal seek for each.

Answer (score 1):

1. Include a formula in a separate cell that calculates `=AC21 - U3`, then set that cell to zero via goalseek. That is, if you put this new formula in cell Z1, set the goal seek parameters to:
   Set cell: Z1
   To value: 0
   By changing cell $U$6
2. The above approach can theoretically be extended to find simultaneous sulltions across any number of cells. E.g., if you want to set U3 equal to AC21, and U4 equal to AC22, you could set the added formula to be Z1 = 'abs(U3-AC21) + abs(U4-AC22)', and goal seek that to zero. But that's rarely going to turn up what you want.

Excel includes a similar but much more powerful (and complicated) tool called "Solver". To make it available, you first need to enable the Solver Add-in (search "Solver" from the main search bar, click on "Add-Ins" and put a checkmark next to "Solver Add-in"). Solver will then show up in the Data ribbon, in a block labeled "Analyze".

Comment: Thank u so much I use Solver Add-in it was very helpful